# TensorFlow _1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue error

Tags: tensorflow

I run a **TensorFlow** tutorial program named **cifar10** from the official TensorFlow website, but while running I got the following error:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128, current size 64)
     [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]
```

What does the error mean? How can I solve it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, input pipelines are typically built from many small subgraphs, connected by queues. This error message (i.e. an `OutOfRangeError`) typically indicates that one of the pipeline stages has been closed, which usually happens when an *earlier* pipeline either (i) runs out of data, or (ii) encounters some other error that causes it to crash. For example, if the files containing the CIFAR-10 dataset could not be found, you might see this error at the end of your logs, but there should be additional information earlier in your logs that indicates the root cause.